# Compare Every 2 row Using Pandas and show the different

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, compare

I have problem with our code to compare every 2 row with different excel file:

[image: Sheat1]

[image: Sheat2]

and we have code to compare every row:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


old_df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', sheet_name="Best Practice Config", names="A", header=None)
new_df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx',sheet_name="Existing Config", names="B", header=None)

compare = old_df[~old_df["A"].isin(new_df["B"])
```

but i need compare 2 row , Please advise what is the best way of pandas to do that.

Comment: It's recommended to add data as text rather than as image, we can not copy the contents from image.

Comment: Also please include what your current vs expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pandas.DataFrame.compare` method. The documentation is available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html).

```
old_df.compare(new_df)
```

I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Yes , I use too, but that same problem, that function compare every 1 row.

Comment: Please, try to use compare method in this way: `old_df[::2].compare(new_df[::2])`.